# How to assign a value of an element created with ajax to a hidden form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There's a div with a button. When you click the button a form appears. The div's id then gets assigned to a hidden field of the form. This works for the divs that are on the page when the page is loaded. It doesn't work for divs that are created by ajax after the page is loaded.

```
<div class=\"maincircle\">
    <div class=\"textcircle\" data-id=\"$name\" onclick=\"displayLevel3('$name');\">". $row['name'] ."</div>
    <button class=\"add1\" id=\"$name\" onclick=\"toggle_visibility('addleaf');\"></button>
    <button class=\"add2\" data-id=\"$name\" onclick=\"toggle_visibility('addsibling');\"></button>
    <button class = \"delete\" data-id= \"$name\"></button>
</div>
```

After clicking 'textcircle', ajax displays more divs with the same layout:

```
    $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
      data : {"node" : val},
      url  : 'displaylevel3.php',
      success: function ( data ) {
        $('#level3').html(data);
      },
      error: function ( xhr ) {
        alert( "error" );
      }
    });

}
```

The following javascript doesn't work for these div's buttons created by ajax:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunc);
}

function clickFunc() {
  var id = this.id; 
  document.getElementById('parent').value = id;
  document.getElementById('sibling').value = id;
}
```

How to assign the value of a button created with ajax to a hidden form field?

Comment: Is it required to use `JavaScript` methods? You can try using `jQuery` instead. Use **alert("Hello World!")** to check if it returns on button click.

Comment: What is `parent` and `sibling`? can you show it's html. It's unclear where they added?

Comment: molihua  did you checked the answer?

Comment: parent and sibling are the ids of the hidden fields of the form. The button's values are supposed to be assigned to these fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use jQuery [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).closest('#parent').val(id);
  $(this).closest('#sibling').val(id);
});
```

Comment: I was supposed to post it and believe, this will easily solve the issue @Alive to Die.

Comment: I think this is the solution too, doing it with even-delegation sounds right. I'm looking into it further. Thank you so much. It must be really stupid, but why aren't the values still not being assigned to the hidden fields (parent and sibling)? not even the ones which are loaded directly on the page now. When I put an alert under var id, I can see it does get the right value.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working with $('#parent').val(id);

Comment: @molihua  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

An answer is already given. You can try using the following as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".add1").click(function() {
           var id = $(this).attr('id');

           alert(id);
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this confirms that there are no values assigned to the buttons which are created with ajax. I'm checking above answer now. I've checked on event delegation and I think that must solve the issue too. I'm trying to make it work. Thank you!